# Can you force document.write when to write to head and when to body?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

`document.write` seems to figure out on its own when to write to the head and when to write to the body.

For example, it writes `<style>` and `<script>` to the head and `<div>` to the body.

Can this automatic behavior be avoided and let the programmer decide what goes where?

I experimented this with iframes. Unfortunately, the internal code box here doesn't seem to support interacting with iframes, so please see it [in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gawd7m10/).

```js
var theiframe=document.getElementById('testing'), output=document.getElementById('output'), thebody=document.getElementById('output_body'), thehead=document.getElementById('output_head'), thebody=document.getElementById('output_body');
console.clear();
console.group('Testing');
theiframe.contentWindow.document.open();
theiframe.contentWindow.document.writeln("<script>var foo1='head';<\/script>");
theiframe.contentWindow.document.writeln("<script>var foo2='body';<\/script>");
theiframe.contentWindow.document.close();
console.log(theiframe.contentWindow.document.documentElement);
thehead.value = theiframe.contentWindow.document.head.innerHTML;
thebody.value = theiframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
console.groupEnd();
```

```css
textarea {width: 50%}
```

```html
Iframe:
<br /><iframe id="testing"></iframe>
<hr>
Iframe's head:
<br /><textarea id="output_head"><</textarea>
<hr>
Iframe's body:
<br /><textarea id="output_body"><</textarea>
```

Comment: Also, read [Why is document.write considered a “bad practice”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/215552)

Comment: I know, I know, but this is just a micro part of a larger project that can't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65596384/4829915%20d), `document.write` can be controlled by specifically using it to declare either or both `<head>` and `<body>`.

For example, `document.write('<style>p {font-size: 1em}<\/style>')` goes to head, but `document.write('<body><style>p {font-size: 1em}<\/style><\/body>')` goes to body.

Likewise, `document.write('<script>var a=2;<\/script>')` goes to head, but `document.write('<body><script>var a=2;<\/script><\/body>')` goes to body.

As mentioned in that answer, it will of course not work on elements that simply can't be in the head, like `<span>` or `<div>`.

See full demonstration [in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fbe0r2a4/) (which supports interaction with iframes).

```js
var theiframe=document.getElementById('testing'), output=document.getElementById('output'), thebody=document.getElementById('output_body'), thehead=document.getElementById('output_head'), thebody=document.getElementById('output_body');
console.clear();
console.group('Testing');
theiframe.contentWindow.document.open();
theiframe.contentWindow.document.write("<head>");
theiframe.contentWindow.document.write("<script>var foo1='head';<\/script>");
theiframe.contentWindow.document.write("<\/head>");
theiframe.contentWindow.document.write("<body>");
theiframe.contentWindow.document.write("<script>var foo2='body';<\/script>");
theiframe.contentWindow.document.write("</body>");
theiframe.contentWindow.document.close();
console.log(theiframe.contentWindow.document.documentElement);
thehead.value = theiframe.contentWindow.document.head.innerHTML;
thebody.value = theiframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
console.groupEnd();
```

```css
textarea {width: 50%}
```

```html
Iframe:
<br /><iframe id="testing"></iframe>
<hr>
Iframe's head:
<br /><textarea id="output_head"><</textarea>
<hr>
Iframe's body:
<br /><textarea id="output_body"><</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` writes the HTML to whatever the next bit of the document is.

It follows the normal rules of HTML. The fact you are using `document.write` doesn't matter.

If you have an HTML document that looks like this:

```
<style>p { ... }</style>
<div>...</div>
```

Then it implicitly creates the `html` element and the `head` element at which point a `style` element is valid and it insert the `style` element there.

Then you have a `div` element. This cannot exist inside the `head`, so it implicitly ends the `head` element and opens the `body` element.

A `script` element is allowed in both the `head` and the `body` so it will end up wherever you put it.

This is just how HTML works.

---

> Can this automatic behavior be avoided and let the programmer decide what goes where?

Some HTML parsers will let you get away with explicitly starting the `body` and then inserting a `style` element. You can't use a hack like that to put a `div` in the `head` though.

```
<body>
<style>p { ... }</style>
<div>...</div>
```

You can also use DOM manipulation (`appendChild` et al) to insert elements in places they don't belong and bypass the HTML parsing rules.

---

Intentionally generating an invalid DOM really isn't a good idea. If you're trying to come up with some kind of hack that needs it, you should probably rethink your entire approach.